# Custom pop-up before closing window

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display a warning message inside a Modal or Toaster before the user closes browser. I usually get this :

[image]

Is there anyway to display something else rather than the default pop-up?

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
    event.returnValue = "\o/"
})
```

Comment: modern browsers do not support it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)